# Creating drop down list with values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, dropdownlist

I want to show a drop down list in the feature attributes dialog.

I have three different building zones. The hot Wohnzon A, B residential zone and residential zone C. Now I have an attribute called the `"Zonenart"`. Now I track a new zone. And instead of the attribute `"Zonenart"` write something purely by hand, I want to be able to select it directly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Mapperz I wouldn't close it just yet.  Creating a custom form isn't really needed just for a drop down list.

Comment: Reopened on Nathan W's request.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open the layer properties dialog and select the fields tab, click the button in the Edit Widgets column for the field and select Value Map

[image]

which will then give you this when using the info tool

[image]

Comment: Very good answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 13):

### For QGIS 3:

Right mouse click over the layer, and then proceed with `Layer Properties > Attributes Form > Fields > [field name]`.

Under "Widget Type", choose "Value Map" in the drop down.

[image: Widget Type]

Comment: Is it possible to create such a value map also on a database level, and not just a project level, so no matter in what QGIS project the user would edit the layer, he would get this dropdown with possible values (like domains in ArcGIS), based on a "value map" table stored in a database ?

Comment: Is it possible to pick a value from the list to be the default rather than a blank value being displayed. I know we can set the defaults but then you need to click on the box to activate it.