# Automatic fill-in value map columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield

I would like to connect my taxon name column (value map) with a new column (scientific name).
How to make a new scientific name autofilled when I choose a taxone name from the list?

For example: I'm choosing name from the list in the column "taxon name": Black woodpecker, and I'd like to my second column autofilled with the right scientific name: Dryocopus martius. I have both lists with names and scientific names in csv.

Comment: Should this happen right away? Otherwise you can do a join with your .CSV with both names on the column with the taxon name once you are back to the office. It's quickly done

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume there is polygon layer called *'test2'* with several features in it, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Create a drop down list with values for the `"TaxonName"` field. Check these threads for more details: [Creating drop down list with values in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list) and [Creating multiple select dropdown list in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306881/creating-multiple-select-dropdown-list-in-qgisv)

[image: step1]

**Step 2.** Generate manually/programmatically [`a map`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map) object from your CSV or list with taxon and scientific names accordingly, e.g. `map(key1,value1,key2,value2…)`.

```
map('Black woodpecker','Dryocopus martius 1','Red woodpecker','Dryocopus martius 2','White woodpecker','Dryocopus martius 3')
```

*sorry if this example is meaningless in terms of zoology*

If you prefer to work with a CSV that contains taxons, then simply drag&drop it into QGIS, see image below.

[image: csv]

**Step 3.** Change the default value for `"Scientific"` field via `Layer Properties > Attributes Form > Fields > [Field] > Defaults`

[image: step3]

using this expression that will contain that map object:

```
if("TaxonName", map_get(map('Black woodpecker','Dryocopus martius 1','Red woodpecker','Dryocopus martius 2','White woodpecker','Dryocopus martius 3'), "TaxonName"), NULL)
```

or another expression if referring to a CSV:

```
if("TaxonName", attribute(get_feature('birds', 'TaxonName', "TaxonName"), 'Scientific'), NULL)
```

and click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Then you achieve the desired output in the `"Scientific"` field after selecting the `"TaxonName"`:

[image: result]

Comment: How to create a map object automatically? I have CSV file with almost 500 species names, it is impossible to create it maually without mistakes :(

Comment: this link doesn't work

Comment: Excellent! This looks really good. Have you tested that it works well in QField?

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you! I'm going to try it in QField :)